# How to draw colored Rectangular on Transparent canvas with Python+tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to draw Colored Rectangular on Transparent Canvas to make Capture Tool with python and tkinter.

But when I draw Colored Rectangular on Transparent Canvas Colored Rectangular are not Shown , because Canvas is Transparent.

I need Transparent Canvas with Non-Transparent Rectangular on it.

thanks.

My steps...

1. Draw Transparent Canvas (canvas size is full screen)
2. and Draw Rectangular on the Canvas
3. i expected Clear Rectangular is Displayed
4. but  Rectangular is Transparent, because Canvas was transparent

   ```
   class Screen(tkinter.Canvas):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           #<create Canvas>
           tkinter.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
           self.master.overrideredirect(True)
           self.vw, self.vh =self.GetScreenSize()
           self.config(width=self.vw, height=self.vh, highlightthickness=0, ="black")
           self.master.overrideredirect(True)
           self.master.geometry("+0+0")
           self.master.lift()
           self.master.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.3)
           self.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
           #<create Rectangular>
           self.create_rectangle(0,0,100,1000,outline='red', width=5)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want to do with tkinter. The `alpha` option affects the entire window and everything drawn on it.